# Java method with variable argument type and quantity

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I did some research into generics and varargs in Java, but I can't seem to find how to implement them together into creating a method (and/or constructor) with flexible argument type and quantity. For example, say I wanted to create a single method could requiring either an array of integers or an unfixed amount of integer arguments. I could create the first as such:

```
public void example0 (int[] args) { }
```

As well as the latter as such:

```
public void example1 (int... args) { }
```

But how could I combine them to be under a single name? And, looking to the future how could I implement support for multiple numeric value types, such as a float? An example would be a great answer.

UPDATE:

Thanks, but apparently I used a too simple of an example for a larger question. How would I approach this considering any number of arguments and any type? So say:

```
public void example(int[] args) {}
public void example(string arg0, int[] args) {}
public void example(string arg0, string arg1) {}
...
```

Comment: Just define the second; you can call it like the first, because the second is syntactic sugar for the first.

Comment: Will this also work with constructors?

Comment: yes, it will work with ctors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public void example1 (int... args) { }` can also accept `int[]`. 
So this is enough.
To accept multiple type of numeric value you could use a generic class which the generic is a subclass of `Number`.

For example :

```
public class Foo<T extends Number> {
   // ...
}
```

And you could use it such as :

```
Foo<Integer> fooInt = new Foo<>();
Foo<Float> fooFloat = new Foo<>();
```

But note that it will be less efficient than primitive because of the unboxing operations. So using overloaded methods with each primitive type is generally advised :

```
public void example1 (int... args) { }
public void example1 (long... args) { }
public void example1 (double... args) { }
```

Answer (score 7):

An `int...` parameter can accept both ints and int arrays. You only need one method to handle both.

```
public void example (int... args) { }
```

Example invocations:

```
example(1, 2, 3);
example(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

> And, looking to the future how could I implement support for multiple numeric value types, such as a float?

You could try to use `Number`, which is a superclass of both `Integer` and `Float`. But honestly, it's awkward and inefficient and not worth it. Standard API methods tend to just have overloads for all the numeric types.

```
public void example (int... args) { }
public void example (long... args) { }
public void example (float... args) { }
public void example (double... args) { }
```

Comment: Be careful when using varargs and arrays, especially when generics are involved. You may accidentally call `<String[]>example()` instead of `<String>example()`

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, both of those methods will compile with the same signature. e.g. vararg is syntactic sugar for creating a new array.

Both methods are equivalent to this.

```
public void example(int[] array)
```